# On an edittext: Can we know if the the number is being read from soft keyboard or barcode reader

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, barcode-scanner

I have a Symbol bluetooth barcode reader, that is being connected to my tablet as a keyboard.
I want to use this barcode reader to scan item's barcodes. But I don't want to user to get confused if he/she used it while some other edittext rather than the item's one was focused. In this case the barcode number is being pasted into any edittext with focus on.

My question is: can we identify the string value being entered to an edittext if it was read from a barcode scanner or soft keyboard?